# Spring Security redirectUri for localhost is using https instead of http

Tags: spring, oauth, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, google-signin

I have used spring security to implement my oauth2 client. I have configured my callback as http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/abc, so when I test my app in my local environment the callback is going to https://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/abc, as https is not valid for localhost my browser is throwing an error because of which I could not test my application loally

```
spring:
      profiles: local
      security:
        oauth2:
          client:
            registration:
              abc:
                client-id: OTExZDE3MGQtZTkyMy00YWZjLWFhZDItMGVmZTI1ZDQ3MGJm
                client-secret: MzNlZWFhNDQtOGE4Mi00NDVkLWFiMTUtZjAzNWE2YmU2YWIz
                authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
                redirectUri: http://localhost:3000/login/oauth2/code/abc
                scope:
                  - openid
                  - internal
            provider:
              abc:
                authorization-uri: https://api.abc.com/oauth/authorize
                token-uri: https://api.abc.com/oauth/token
                jwk-set-uri: https://api.abc.com/oauth/keys
```

Comment: Please add your Security code, You must have added configuration to redirect to https

Comment: no, I did not add https to neither my configuration nor in callback configuration at oauth provider

Comment: Which Spring security version did you use?

Answer (score 0):

How about this configuration?

```
security.oauth2.client.use-current-uri=false
```

The JavaDoc of `AbstractRedirectResourceDetails.isUseCurrentUri()` says as follows.

> *Flag to signal that the current URI (if set) in the request should be used in preference to the pre-established redirect URI.*

Comment: no...it is still using https and getting redirected to https://localhost:3000/login/oauth2/code/abc, I have set the flag as useCurrentUri: false in application.yml right after the redirectUri in the above config.